# Is JSON.stringify() reliable for serializing JSON objects?

Tags: php, javascript, json, serialization, stringification

I need to send full objects from Javascript to PHP.  It seemed pretty obvious to do JSON.stringify() and then json_decode() on the PHP end, but will this allow for strings with ":" and ","?  Do I need to run an escape() function on big user input strings that may cause an issue?  What would that escape function be?  I don't think escape works for my purposes.

Are there any downsides to JSON.stringify() I need to know about?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's reliable in any decent implementation (like [Crockford's](http://www.json.org/js.html)), and no, you don't have to run it through `escape` first (if you do that, PHP will be pretty confused at the other end). Browsers are starting to get their own implementations of JSON stuff (now that it's in the [5th edition spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)), but for now, you may be best off using Crockford's or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good description of what JSON.stringify() does here:

http://www.json.org/js.html

The source code is also available if you want to be certain and/or make changes.

I have been using it for months without problem.

Also,
I'm not sure if you have seen the man page for json_decode, lots of good info there aswell:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

HTH